# application looks for testNG.xml in wrong folder

Tags: webdriver, testng

Really hope i'll find an answer for this :-) 
I started to write automated tests using webdriver+testNG and everything was fine. But now i created a new project and when i try to run it ( click on class->run as testNG test) i see an error message like:
An internal error occurred during: "Launching test".
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\workspace\OriginalProject\testng.xml (The system cannot find the file specified) .

But I dont use the OriginalProject at all right now. 
Seems that that path is still present in some place!?
If I start by clicking the correct  testng.xml file , it works fine !?

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Check your testng settings at window->preferences->testng.  You might have specified your default testng XML there and all projects wud try to use the same one.